# Passing Spring MVC authorization info to Angular/NodeJS application pages

Tags: node.js, angular, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are having Spring MVC application which has been developed over last seven to eight years. It has Spring authentication for all its users. Once user logs in, he/she lands on the main page of the application. Application has MSSQL Database.

Now recently we have developed pages in AngularJS + NodeJS. These pages use same MSSQL DB to generate some reports to display them in frontend developed in Angular. We want to launch these pages using menu items in Spring application's main page. However, we don't want our user to login again on Angular application page to see reports.

**Question:** How can Spring authorization information (which could be inside header, cookies etc.) be transferred to Angular/NodeJS stack? Is there any standard way provided by Spring to transfer authentication to third party application?

**What has been tried so far?**

Using Inspect, I found authentication parameters Spring sends to its backend. But I am not sure how exactly am I going to collect them in Spring application? And even after I send them to NodeJS via Angular frontend, how to validate them with Spring from there?

Any directions will be really really appreciated. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: iframe the application and read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for the link. There are lots of points been discussed wrt cross-domain. However, our is same domain only tech-stacks are different.